# Convert String to System.Decimal in java

Tags: java

I have a need of inserting into variable which is of type `System.Decimal` through java code.
I tried using float and double in java. but seems like it is not accepting.

Any idea which is the equivalent datatype in java to datatype of `System.Decimal` in C#.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you please show what you wrote ??

Comment: Are you using IKVM.NET or something like that?

Comment: obj.setValue(Float.parseFloat("StringValue")). achually am trying to insert values(through java code) into table whose feild is declared of type "System.Decimal".it says "mismatch :inserted value is of type "System.single"(for parsing to float value) but expecting "System.Decimal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best equivalent would probably be [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). It't arbitrary-precision instead of the fixed precision of `System.Decimal` but it's exact decimal arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a C# System.Decimal in a Java application ????

Do you want an object instead of a primitive type float or double, then you have the class java.lang.Double. Using autoboxing of Java you can write code like

```
Double d = 0.3;
```

or not using autoboxing you can write

```
Double d = new Double(0.3);
```

if you have a String then you can use

```
Double d = Double.valueOf("0.3");
```

The class Double as an object class or the type double as primitive have the same properties regarding precision etc... if you want higher precision you can use the BigDecimal class.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.3");
```

Comment: Database is implemented based on C#. m integrating to it or in other words, trying to insert values into the feild through java code.the feild accepts value of type "System.Decimal"

Comment: Perhaps you meant `double` instead of `Double`.

Comment: thanks all,:):)..it worked for me using this. ConverterUtil.convertToDecimal("StringValue"). which is in "Apache.axis2"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a String and want to convert it into a format that supports decimal values...

```
String value = "12.34";
Float f = Float.valueOf(value);
```

Comment: @Joey, thanks. I was refering to the basic meaning of decimal (simply a number that may have fraction units). As others have already posted, `BigDecimal` would possibly be the better option.